# /etc/init.d/networking start errors with "network stop:waiting"

Tags: linux, networking, vmware-fusion, backtrack

**System:** I'm on a BT5r3 image atop of VMware Fusion 5 on OSX 10.7.4

I spin up the VM, login, run `startx`, then hop in a terminal to run `service networking start`. I have just one interface configured in to bridge to my wireless network, which I'm on.

As of last reboot, I keep getting the error `network stop:waiting` when trying to run it. `restart`  and `stop` don't help either. `/etc/network/interfaces` is setup just fine and even bypassing it with `ifup` errors:

> `$ ifup eth0`
>
> `SIOCSIFADDR: No such device`
> `eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device`
> `eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device`
> `Bind socket to interface: No such device`
> `Failed to bring up eth0.`

This has previously worked. Any recommendations on how to proceed?

Thanks, `mjb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the interface shows up when you run `/sbin/ifconfig -a`. If it's there, make sure the name of the device hasn't changed from `eth0`.

If there is no interface there, check your virtual machine settings to ensure that the bridge is still configured.

Are the vmware-tools installed?

Also remember that `ifup`/`ifdown`, `/etc/init.d/networking`,  `service` only work as root.

Comment: `ifconfig -a` is showing eth4, 5 and 6. Does it make sense to edit /etc/network/interfaces to eth4 instead of 0?

Comment: I reinstalled tools just in case... and then ran dhclient. Now I'm connected. Not sure why. Correct answer goes to whomever can explain what little logic there was in my actions. Cheers.

Comment: Just realizing I didn't give credit where it was due! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you copy the linux virtual machine (in this case is BackTrack 5 R 3 vmware version) from an external disk or from a directory to a new directory in your computer then run it at first time, there is a notification to “I Copied it” or “I Move it” . Usually if you choose “I Move it” and after entering the desktop by `startx`, then you’re trying to `ifconfig eth0 up` via terminal  there is an error appears:

> eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device.

That’s because the virtual machine couldn’t detect the interface and couldn’t generate the interface rule (`70-persistent-net.rules`) file  in the `/etc/udev` correctly.

How to solve? It’s very simple just remove the interface rule:

```
root@bt:~# mv /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules   /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules.old
```

Then reboot your machine.

Try to check the interface again via terminal  using : ifconfig -a , make sure there is  “eth0″.